# Custom rotation function in C with SDL 1.2 not really working

Tags: c, rotation, sdl, sdl-1.2

I have to do an OCR for scholar purposes.
I don't know if I can use embedded rotation functions in SDL so I've written a basic rotation function.
It seems to work but I have some problems: It works only with some image and when it works, the new image is kinda messy. Example:

Image before rotation:

[image]

Image after 60 degree rotation:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "image.h"

double deg_to_rad(int angle)
{
    return (angle*0.017453292519943);
}

SDL_Surface *rotate(SDL_Surface *image, int angle)
{
    /* Trigo */
    double cosa = cos(deg_to_rad(angle));
    double sina = sin(deg_to_rad(angle));

    int wo = abs((image->w)*cosa + (image->h)*sina);
    int ho = abs((image->h)*cosa + (image->w)*sina);


    /* Création d'une nouvelle image */
    SDL_Surface *new_img;
    Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;

    #if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
            rmask = 0xff000000;
            gmask = 0x00ff0000;
            bmask = 0x0000ff00;
            amask = 0x000000ff;
    #else
            rmask = 0x000000ff;
            gmask = 0x0000ff00;
            bmask = 0x00ff0000;
            amask = 0xff000000;
    #endif

    new_img = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,wo,ho,32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
    int center_x = image->w / 2;
    int center_y = image->h / 2;
    int new_center_x = wo/2;
    int new_center_y = ho/2;
    for (int x = 0; x < wo; x++)
    {
            for (int y = 0; y < ho; y++)
            {
                    int xo = abs(cosa*(x - new_center_x) + sina*(y - new_center_y) + center_x);
                    int yo = abs((-1)*sina*(x - new_center_x) + cosa*(y - new_center_y) + center_y);

                    lockSurface(image);
                    lockSurface(new_img);

                    Uint8 r,g,b;
                    Uint32 pixel;
                    Uint32 color;
                    if (xo >= 0 && yo >= 0 && xo < image->w && yo < image->h
                        && x >= 0 && x < wo && y >=0 && y < ho)
                    {
                            pixel = getPixel(image, xo, yo);
                            SDL_GetRGB(pixel, image->format, &r, &g, &b);
                            color = SDL_MapRGB(image->format, r, g, b);
                            setPixel(new_img, x, y, color);
                    }

                    unlockSurface(image);
                    unlockSurface(new_img);
            }
    }
    return new_img;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine the image as a "grid" of pixels, it will be clear why your function is distorting it - rotating that grid does not map pixels to pixels, and by taking the value of just one closest pixel pre-rotation and inserting it into the post-rotation pixel, you're somewhat literally "cutting corners".  You'll want to use an area-mapping or supersampling algorithm to avoid those visual artifacts you are seeing - this means considering the pixel "shape" in the first case and mixing the parts of the "pixel squares" together, if that makes sense?

The pictures (and code!) in ["A Fast Algorithm for General Raster Rotation" by Alan W. Paeth](http://www.cipprs.org/papers/VI/VI1986/pp077-081-Paeth-1986.pdf) are worth many words.